# How can I resample the random number until a given condition is met?

Tags: python, random

Here's part of the code I'm working on:

```
def get_noise(measures, errors):
    noisy_measures = []
    for i,j in zip(measures, errors):
        added = i + np.random.normal(scale = j)
        while added < 0:
            added = i + np.random.normal(scale = j) # Question Here!
        noisy_measures.append()
    return noisy_measures
```

The number `added` is a sum of fixed number `measures` and a random number sampled from a normal distribution, which might be negative. I wonder how can I add some conditions to make `added` non-negative? I'm trying to do something marked in the code but it seems like that doesn't work.

How can I resample the random value until `added` is non-negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple possibility is to "cap" the `added` final value at 0 by using `added = max(added, 0)`.

This way, you'll exactly solve your issue. However, it means that you could have a "cluster" at the value zero.

I'd recommend reducing the noise, or trying to scale down the noise on the negative side, depends on your actual model of course.

To do the other possibility, the resampling you asked for, you'll need to resample "as long at it is invalid", like this:

```
    for i,j in zip(measures, errors):
        added = -1
        while added < 0: 
            added = i + np.random.normal(scale = j)

        # ok, 'added' must be non-negative here
```

This implies the distribution will be skewed as well (of course), but maybe more "uniformly" around the measure.